# Custom Class to Wordpress Navigation Anchor Tags

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I'm currently using a theme that has a custom menu. I have a navigation that contains 6 links. What I'm trying to do is add different background images to the anchor tags inside the list items of the navigation. If I use the built in css custom classes option Wordpress has for the navigation items, the custom classes are added to the list items, which is not what I need.

What I do need is to add different classes to each navigation item's anchor tag. I tried removing the $class_names variable from the list item and adding it to the anchor tag, but then the active and hover states of the navigation stop working.

```
<li><a href="#" class="icon white"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icon black"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icon yellow"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icon blue"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icon red"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icon green"></a></li>

class Maha_Mega_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"nav-sub-menus\"><ul>\n";
}

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul></div>\n";
}

function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {

    global $wp_query;
    $cat = $item->object_id;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $class_names = $value = '';
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
    $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $children = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent',
        'meta_value' => $item->ID
    ));
    // echo $depth.' x ';
    if ( ! empty( $children ) || ! get_field( 'menu_latest_posts', 'category_' . $cat ) || get_field( 'menu_latest_posts', 'category_' . $cat ) == 'latest_posts_on' ) {
        // if ( $depth == 0 && $item->object == 'category' || $item->object == 'page' ) {
        if ( $depth == 0 && $item->object == 'category' || $item->object == 'page' || $item->object == 'custom' ) {
            $item_output  .= '<div class="nav-sub-wrap container"><div class="nsw row">';
        }
    }
    $item_output .= $args->after;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS itself-

```
<style>
    li:nth-child(1) a {
        background-image: url('//imageurl');
    }
    li:nth-child(2) a {
        background-image: url('//imageurl');
    }
   ...
   ...

    li:nth-child(6) a {
        background-image: url('//imageurl');
    }
</style>
```